# Open recent files buffer (recentf-mode) filled with autoload.el files

Tags: files, recentf

I've a problem with recentf-mode buffer in emacs. Apart from the files I opened before, its also showing all the autoload files for various packages I've installed which is cluttering the Open recent buffer with unnecessary items. Like so :- [image]

How can I stop emacs from doing this?

Comment: Provide a recipe to repro the problem, starting with `emacs -Q`. Otherwise it is difficult to guess what you might have done that causes the problem.

Comment: @Drew can you please elaborate on what you mean by provide a recipe ? I've started to use emacs very recently and I'm lost as to what I should do.

Comment: Tell us, step by step, how to reproduce what you see, starting from **`emacs -Q`** (no init file). Whatever is needed to reproduce this should be part of the recipe, and extraneous stuff should not be part of it. And tell us just what you see the is different from what you expected to see.

Comment: Here's what I did :- 

1. launched emacs with `emacs -Q` .

2. Opened the scratch buffer and evaluated '(recentf-mode 1)' to enable open recent files.

3. executed the command `recentf-open-files` to launch the "Open Recent" buffer. 


I see the exact same result as shown in my first post. I'm confused now, are the autoloads.el files supposed to show up in the Open Recent buffer ? Is this how it works for everyone ?

Comment: Got it; thx. I don't know the answer to your question, though. It does seem odd that files full of autoloads would be added to your recent-files list. I don't load such files, so when I use your recipe I don't see such entries. Hopefully someone else can either tell you why seeing these is a good thing or confirm that this is not a good thing (is a bug).

Comment: Okay, so to test recent-files list, I opened about 20 files, closed my emacs session and reopened emacs and executed `recentf-open-files` and suddenly, the autoload.el files have magically disappeared(I had about 15 of them before). All I'm left with are the files that I had opened. This is very strange and puzzling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `recentf-exclude` may help you.

cf. https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3g468d/stop_recent_files_showing_elpa_packages/